# How do you run Trac on a public server?

Tags: iis, trac, mod-python, isapi-redirect

Since the TFS is too big for our project, we want to use subversion and Trac. The hosting environment is Windows 2003 and IIS.

There are some options:

1. Run tracd
2. Run Apache with mod_python
3. Run tracd with [AJP Protocol](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/ajp/ajpv13a.html) and the isapi-redirector

We tend to integrate Trac with IIS and the isapi-redirector. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking two questions, how do I run it and what would I suggest.

1. I run it with Apache.
2. I suggest doing it that way (no surprise).

I feel that running with a web server gives you more flexibility and
running with Apache gives you more portability.

On the other hand, the *fact* of running it is more important than *how* you do so.

Cheers,
Glenn

Comment: Have you had any difficutlties with python and mod_python on that setup?

Answer (score 0):

We run Apache listening on port 443 (https) for Trac and Svn (WebDAV), and IIS listening on port 80 (http) for public web pages. Setting up Apache for Trac and Svn was very easy and well documented.